# How to use Model information as function parameters

Tags: swift, model

I have this Model:

```
struct ModelGlider {

static var arr_Glider2DT:[[//Array 2D with Tuple
    (
        gliderSeats:Int,
        gliderMass :Double,
        gliderName :String
    )
]] = [[]] //empty Array 2DT

init(arr_Glider2DT:
    [[
        (
            gliderSeats:Int,
            gliderMass :Double,
            gliderName :String
        )
    ]]
    ){ModelGlider.arr_Glider2DT = arr_Glider2DT}
}
```

In a function I would like to use the model information as input and return parameters.
Insted of:

```
func searchGlidersForString(
    searchString:String,
    inputArr2DT :[[
        (
            gliderSeats:Int,
            gliderMass :Double,
            gliderName :String
        )
    ]]) -> [[
        (
            gliderSeats:Int,
            gliderMass :Double,
            gliderName :String
        )
    ]]
{
    //do some stuff
    return ...
}
```

I would prefer something like:

```
func searchGlidersForString(
    searchString:String,
    inputArr2DT : ModelGlider.arr_Glider2DT) -> ModelGlider.arr_Glider2DT
{
    //do some stuff
    return ….
}
```

It's embarrassing, but I can't figure out what I’m missing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a custom `typealias`:

```
typealias ArrGlider2DT = [[ // Array 2D with Tuple
    (
        gliderSeats: Int,
        gliderMass: Double,
        gliderName: String
    )
]]
```

and use it like this:

```
struct ModelGlider {
    static var arr_Glider2DT: ArrGlider2DT = [[]] // empty Array 2DT

    init(arr_Glider2DT: ArrGlider2DT) {
        Self.arr_Glider2DT = arr_Glider2DT
    }
}

func searchGlidersForString(
    searchString: String,
    inputArr2DT: ArrGlider2DT
) -> ArrGlider2DT {
    // do some stuff
    return ...
}
```